# Is it possible to use Begin and End inside a Manipulate?

Tags: programming, dynamic, manipulate, contexts

May be someone can explain why I can't use `` Begin["context`"] `` and `End[]` inside a `Manipulate` expression, or inside the initialization section?

When I use it in the `Manipulate` expression, and close the notebook and restart, I get the error:

[image]

Here is the code, please feel free to modify as needed. I am just trying to see if the idea of different contexts can be used inside Manipulate. It is just not seeing `` obj`f[] `` at all.

```
Manipulate[

 Begin["obj`"];
 f[y_] := y^2 + 1;
 End[];

 {x, Date[], obj`f[1]},

 {{x, 0, "x"}, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {x}
 ]
```

I also tried in the initialization section, same problem. I think this is because `Manipulate` itself is a `Dynamic` module, it does not like new context created inside it?

This is a snapshot of the above:

```
DynamicModule[{x = 5}, 
     Begin["obj`"]; 
     f[y_] := y^2 + 1; 
     End[]; 
     {x, Date[], obj`f[1]}
 ]
```

Outside `Manipulate`, it works fine of course: (restating kernel helps before running this below again after the above just in case)

```
Begin["obj`"];
f[y_] := y^2 + 1;
End[];

obj`f[2]
```

gives `5`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917550/why-doesnt-this-use-of-begin-work

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Short answer: yes, it is possible.

The problem is that parsing is done line-by-line only for the top-level code. For code inside some head(s), it is first parsed as a whole. Therefore, your `f` is parsed to `` Global`f ``, and this is why that symbol is used. Here is what you can do, schematically:

```
DynamicModule[{x = 5},
 With[{def = MakeBoxes[f[y_] := y^2 + 1;], ff = MakeBoxes[f]},
   Block[{$ContextPath},
     BeginPackage["obj`"];
     ReleaseHold[MakeExpression@ff];
     Begin["`Private`"];
     ReleaseHold[MakeExpression@def];
     End[];
     EndPackage[]]
 ];
 {x, Date[], obj`f[1]}]
```

What we do here is to delay the parsing (or, more precisely, the last stage of it)  of our definition until run-time, converting it first to boxes and thus preventing its premature parsing. I used a similar technique in my answer in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/c1f4ab24db8a8542). We could have converted to strings, but I prefer boxes as being still "on this side of Mathematica".

Note that a side effect of this code is that a symbol `f` is still created in the context which is current when the code executes (`` Global` `` here). If you want to avoid that, you could insert `Remove[f]`  before `Block`. I went all the way to use `` `Private` `` sub-context, to avoid polluting the current context with some auxiliary symbols created during assignments.

You can also automate this code with some meta-programming.

Comment: `ReleaseHold[MakeExpression@ff];` can be simplified to `ToExpression[ff]`, right?

Comment: @xzczd Looks like that. I can't remember now, what was the reason to use this longer form.