# Organizing similar datasets using DownValues instead of Contexts

Tags: import, data-format, downvalues

In his answer to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/organizing-similar-datasets-using-contexts-or-otherwise), Leonid helped me find a way to programmatically generate contexts for holding sets of symbols with the same names. Perhaps a simpler way is to use `DownValues` so:

```
dataRaw["Paris"] = Import["Paris.csv"];
data["Paris"] = Differences[dataRaw["Paris"]];
dataMax["Paris"] = Max[dataRaw["Paris"]];

dataRaw["Madrid"] = Import["Madrid.csv"];
data["Madrid"] = Differences[dataRaw["Madrid"]];
dataMax["Madrid"] = Max[dataRaw["Madrid"]];
```

lets me make a plot using

```
ListLinePlot[data /@ {"Paris", "Madrid"}]
```

and can be implemented with a simple function

```
importCity[cityName_String] := (
    dataRaw[cityName] = Import[cityName ~~ ".csv"];
    data[cityName] = Differences[dataRaw[cityName]];
    dataMax[cityName] = Max[dataRaw[cityName]];
)
```

Other than cluttering everything with a lot of `[cityName]`, are there hidden perils to using `DownValues` in this way? Is there some disadvantage to storing every `dataRaw` as `DownValues` of the same symbol instead of individually in multiple contexts?

Comment: Why use `"paris"` and `ToLowerCase` rather than simply `"Paris"`?

Comment: Good question. That's a holdover from the context method, where (I guess) it's not a good idea to have capitalized context names. I'll update the example.

Comment: Actually, in a user context you are free and clear to use capitalized symbol names because there will be no collisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no other answer has been posted yet I'll give my opinion.

Using `DownValues`, which I believe is a hash table of sorts, is the normal and accepted way to store this kind of information in *Mathematica*, to the best of my knowledge.  I cannot think of any real disadvantages compared to direct symbol assignment.

Either form (direct assignment or DownValues) may take up considerably more memory than storing the information in large array, packed or sparse if possible.  The nature of the data and how it is accessed best determine which method to use.

The other option you should be aware of is to use replacement rules.  When optimized using `Dispatch` this will be similar to `DownValues` in many ways, but it allows different usages and has strengths that can make it superior in some applications.

```
data = Dispatch @ {"Madrid" -> 7, "Paris" -> 2, "Porto" -> 4, "Perth" -> 1};

{"Madrid", "Paris"} /. data
```

> ```
> {7, 2}
> ```

---

By the way you can write `importCity` like this:

```
importCity[cityName_String] :=
  With[{raw = Import[cityName ~~ ".csv"]},
    dataRaw[cityName] = raw;
    data[cityName]    = Differences @ raw;
    dataMax[cityName] = Max @ raw;
  ]
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this way of storing data extensively for what I do. I collected in my answer here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/999/66 several ideas I developed over time around this type of structure. The Keys function based on what dreeves once submitted on StackOverflow ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/154704/884752 ) is what makes this structure practical as you can see all the indices of a symbol used to index its values.

I was lucky to have found this data structure as I began learning Mathematica because it allowed me to do things I couldn't have done without it.

```
SetAttributes[RemoveHead, {HoldAll}];
RemoveHead[h_[args___]] := {args};
NKeys[_[symbol_Symbol]]:=NKeys[symbol]; (*for the head[object] case*)
NKeys[symbol_] := RemoveHead @@@ DownValues[symbol(*,Sort->False*)][[All,1]];
Keys[symbol_] := Replace[NKeys[symbol], {x_} :> x, {1}];

a["b"]=2;
a["c",1]=3;
Keys[a]
```

Comment: This reminds me "dict" in python. Good way to get all the keys quickly.

Answer (score 3):

In contrast to symbols, part replacement with downvalues requires use of a temporary variable, (unless there is a better way).  E.g.

[image]

Comment: I momentarily voted for this, but I am not sure how this relates to the comparison of *symbols* to DownValues.  Do you mean an array?

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard. Yes, an array or list. If symbol `a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` part replacement can be done, but if `f[1] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` it is not so straightforward.

Comment: This is the main drawback of this data structure. The best solution to this is in my opinion something like f[1] = ReplacePart[f[1], 3 -> 6]

Comment: @ Faysal. More complex replacements like `a[[{3, 4}]] = {1, 2}` would be cumbersome to set up. Then I would use the `temp` variable.

Comment: Alright. +1  It might be an interesting question to ask what cleanest method to effect that operation is.