# Does one need to be careful about loading multiple (many) contexts or packages in the same session?

Tags: front-end, performance-tuning, packages, contexts

I have a number of large pieces of precomputed data which I am considering putting into individual packages in order to load them (via `DeclarePackage`) and unload them (via Leonid Shifrin's `PackageManipulations` package) as needed. For what it's worth, I have some functions which will be defined on some objects using `UpValues`, and it is the `UpValues` which will be stored in the packages, one for each object.

I am wondering if performance or other issues occur, either in the kernel or the front end, when any of the following becomes large (hundreds or thousands):

1) `$Packages`,

2) The number of defined contexts,

3) `$ContextPath`.

Is it okay to create new contexts more-or-less at one's convenience, or does one need to be conservative, and if so, how?

Some other questions in which this situation might occur are [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/organizing-similar-datasets-using-contexts-or-otherwise), [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9571/globally-loading-packages-while-using-a-cellgroup-as-the-default-context), and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17916/for-any-symbol-how-can-i-get-the-full-context-qualified-name-of-the-symbol-as-a) (in Leonid Shifrin's answer.

Comment: I have not tried this with so many contexts, but I had once a discussion about this with one of the kernel developers who knows more about this, and he told me that there might be problems with scaling to a huge number of contexts, since the package system has not been originally designed with millions of simultaneously loaded packages / contexts in mind. Regardless of whether or not there will be problems with so many contexts, I would not keep many contexts on `$ContextPath` - normally this is never needed, and you can always group them so that at any given time, you only need a few.

Comment: @Leonid Perhaps it is time to post that as an answer?