# Local variables in Module leak into the Global context

Tags: scoping, symbols, contexts, parsing

From the *Mathematica* documentation on [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html):

> Module allows you to set up local variables with names that are local to the module.

But after using `Module`, the symbol is created !

I understand that `Module` makes temporary symbols appending a number, like `i$8071` and those are gone afterwards.  However the symbol `i` is newly created, but has no value or attributes.

Here is a very simple session showing this.

```
Names["Global`*"]
{}

Module[{i}, Table[i^2, {i, 0, 10}]]
{0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100}

Names["Global`*"]
{"i"}

Attributes[i]
{}
```

This is not causing me any specific trouble currently, but I want to ensure that the code I'm developing is "clean" in that it doesn't pollute the `Global` namespace with new symbols.  Could these unwanted symbols cause trouble by shadowing symbols from other packages for example?  Should I just not worry about it?  How can I check that my code is "clean"?

Comment: You don't even need to specify the `i` in the `Module` variable declaration, the `i` from the `Table` specification will leak out also.

Comment: I'm new to stackexchange and was unaware of how to do this.  Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @owler thank *you* and I'm glad you're happy with the answer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Symbols are created in the current context during parsing.  This should not be a problem in normal circumstances as the symbols are merely "initialized" without values or properties.

See these posts for more information:

- [Is it possible to use Begin and End inside a Manipulate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/595/121)
- [Why doesn't this use of Begin[] work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7917550/618728)
- [When does Mathematica create a new Symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5616966/618728)
- [Scope within Context](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10395/121)

---

You raise good questions in the comments and I need to address them.

### Shadowing

Indeed you can have problems with shadowing due to this.  I intended the linked questions above to serve as examples of (and possible solutions to) this problem, but here is a short description.  In a new session, if you do:

```
Table[x, {x, 3}];

session`x = 5;

AppendTo[$ContextPath, "session`"];

Information["x"]
```

> Global`x

You can see that even though `x` was used in a localizing construct (`Table`) the Symbol `` Global`x `` was created.  This then causes a shadowing problem if we also define `` session`x `` and hope to access it with merely `x` by including `` "session`" `` in the `$ContextPath`.

There are some alternatives to the bare form above that prevent the creation of `` Global`x ``.

#### Precedence of initialization

If you know you are going to use `` session`x `` you can initialize it first, and then if the context name is in `$ContextPath` the appearance of `x` in `Table` will be assumed to be `` session`x `` (`` Global`x `` will not be created):

```
session`x;
AppendTo[$ContextPath, "session`"];
Table[x, {x, 3}];
Information["x"]
```

> session`x

#### Formal Symbols

You could use Formal Symbols in constructs like `Table`, `Block`, and `With` and `Module`.  These symbols exist specifically to prevent conflicts of various kinds as they bear the attribute `Protected` and cannot accidentally have values assigned to them.  (These are entered with e.g. <kbd>Esc</kbd>`$x`<kbd>Esc</kbd> and look much better in the Notebook than they do here.)

```
Table[\[FormalX], {\[FormalX], 3}];
session`x = 5;
AppendTo[$ContextPath, "session`"];
Information["x"]
```

> session`x
>
> x=5

#### `Begin` and `End`

You can use `Begin` and `End`, but as the second linked question above shows you have to be particular in their use: you must evaluate `Begin` on a line before the code that uses the symbols you do not want to "leak" to `` Global` ``:

```
Begin["session`"];

Table[x, {x, 3}];

End[];

Information["x"]
```

> Information::notfound: Symbol x not found. >>

It *cannot* be rolled into a `Module` or other compound expression because the expression is parsed as a whole *before* `Begin` has any effect.  (Workarounds do exist; see the answers to the first linked Q&A above.)

```
Module[{null},
  Begin["session`"];
  Table[x, {x, 3}];
  End[];
]

Information["x"]
```

> Global`x

### The mechanism of `Module`

You asked of this statement was correct:

> Module only makes the value (and Attributes) of the symbol "local". The symbol still gets created in the current Context (Global by default), and can therefore shadow any similar name from another Context.

It is not.  The creation of the `` Global` `` symbol (or as you correctly note whatever the current context is) is merely *incidental* to its use in `Module`.  `Module` has nothing to do with it one way or the other, as it occurs during parsing, before `Module` even has any meaning (it is just another token at that stage).

For reference, `Module` works by creating a new symbol with a name based on the one you give it (`x`), appending `$` and an incrementing number to form e.g. `x$173`.  This symbol is then used in place of all explicit appearances of `x` inside the `Module`.  This new symbol is not itself replaced with `x` at the end so you will see the internal form if it is returned in the output of `Module`, e.g. `Module[{x}, x]`.  See this thread for a more complete description and a comparison to other scoping constructs:

[What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/121)

Comment: Thx, but: this "inadvertent creation of symbols that I don't want to exist" means that the whole problem of "shadowing symbols from other packages" is much more likely to happen.  So, I would say it *could* be a problem.  Is this summary correct: Module only makes the *value* (and Attributes) of the symbol "local".  The symbol still gets created in the current Context (Global by default), and can therefore shadow any similar name from another Context.

Comment: @owler two points: (1) You're quite right, shadowing *can* be a problem and I should have addressed that. (2) Your understanding of `Module` is not correct.  I shall try to extend my answer to cover both these points later today.

Comment: @owler I have made my additions.  Please review the answer and let me know if anything remains unclear.

Comment: Thx, that’s helpful, especially the bit about the parser generating the symbol.  I’m used to Java (or C) where the compiler erases symbols after leaving a scope.  Seems like in Mma the compiler/interpreter is always active and never forgets stuff unless you do `Remove` or such.  I imagine this is because of the rule-rewriting nature of Mma.  I clearly have a lot to learn to grok Mma.

Comment: Coming from Java, the Mma contexts seem similar to the Java package mechanism.  In Java, you `include` a name `foo` from a package, so that you can refer to `foo` without the full package name like `com.baz.bar.foo`.  In Mma, `foo` matches the first `foo` found along the `$ContextPath`.  Just something to get used to.

Comment: @owler: Mathematica does not erase symbols but *collects garbage*. In that sense, it is similar to C#.

Comment: From the discussion above, it appears local variables as used in C#, C++  functions and other languages are not quite analogous to local variables in Mathematica.  One very interesting topic would be a continuation of this thread that outlines methods or patterns that could be used to more closely mimic scoping in other languages.

Comment: Mr. Wizard, this is a very good answer. But no one ever explains *why* MMA is doing this. On the one hand it doesn't seem to matter if the symbols are never actually given values, but on the other hand with a big package (say) one can easily end up with thousands of such 'leaked' variables that must be taking up some memory, and which also pose some sort of security risk too, it would seem.