# Feedback on Functional Programming: Propagation of uncertainty

Tags: functional-style, code-review

Lately I've been trying to use functional prgramming and tried to implement the gaussian propagation of uncertainty (without correlation) in an elegant way, here is the outcome:

```
Norm /@ (#2 Outer[(Derivative @@ #2)@f @@ #1 &, #1, 
  IdentityMatrix@Last@Dimensions@#1, 1] /. f -> #3) &[data, error, f]
```

`data` and `error` are assumed to be two dimensional lists (lists of data points), and `f` is a function. What bothers me a bit is the `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) rule for f, because I couldn't figure out how to create a function `g` in a way that `Outer[g &, ...]&` takes f as an argument to return a new function `g[f]&`, which again takes two arguments (here a partial derivative of f respect to the variable specified by the first argument, evaluated at a point specified by the second argument).

What I ask for basically is some feedback. What could be done better? Any suggestions are appreciated, merci.

Comment: Well, I don't have any feedback on your code right now, but I implemented this already [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16793/#16803) (in fact, this question might even be considered a duplicate). Have a look and see what you think.

Comment: Mathematica 12 now has a built-in function called [Around](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html) to handle this.

Answer (score 8):

The replace is unnecessary here. When I see this right, then your only issue is, that you use the slot `#3` inside the inner pure function. There, it would be belong semantically to the inner function but you want it to be the parameter of the outer one.

This can be solved by using only for the inner function the `(#...)&` syntax. For the outer one, you use the full `Function` where you can name parameters. This should solve your problem and removes the ugly replace

```
Norm /@ Function[{dat, err, fun}, 
   err Outer[(Derivative @@ #2)@fun @@ #1 &, dat, 
     IdentityMatrix@Last@Dimensions@dat, 1]][data, error, f]
```

The above should give the same result but is by far better readable since you don't have to search which `Slot` (`#`) belongs to which function.

Answer (score 1):

I typically use `With` in cases such as this.  Using `With` does not leave a stray reference to `` Global`f `` and it substitutes the value directly into the expression before evaluation, rather than after as your use of `ReplaceAll` does.

```
With[{f = #3},
  Norm /@ (#2 Outer[(Derivative @@ #2)@f @@ # &, #, IdentityMatrix@Last@Dimensions@#1, 1])
] &[data, error, f]
```

I also note that given the statement: "`data` and `error` are assumed to be two dimensional lists" you can shorten `IdentityMatrix@Last@Dimensions@#1` a bit by just checking the length of one of the elements: `IdentityMatrix@Length@Last@#`.  If you wanted to "Golf" the code you could use `DiagonalMatrix[#[[1]]^0]`. :-)