# Add a letter to a variable name from a list

Tags: variable-definitions

Basically I am searching for a way to add the letter `u` to an existing list of variables `{a,b,c,d}` to obtain the variable list `{ua,ub,uc,ud}`.
I am trying to make an function for an automatic calculation of the propagation of uncertainty.

```
U[term_Expression, varlist_Expression] := Sqrt[
Sum[i,{i,
Function[var,
  Power[D[term, var], 2]*u] /@ varlist
}]]
```

The Input `U[a*b, {a, b}]` gives me `Sqrt[a^2*u + b^2*u]` but I want it to be `Sqrt[a^2*ua + b^2*ub]`.
Probably this is a very easy task but I am struggling for hours with this small problem. Maybe you know a solution? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Made it with

```
U[term_, varlist_] := Sqrt[Sum[i, {i,
 Power[
  Function[var,
     D[term, var]
     ] /@ varlist*
   ToExpression[StringInsert[#, "u", 1] & /@ ToString /@ varlist]
  , 2]
 }]]
```

Thank you!

Comment: To make a string out of a symbol `sym`, use `ToString[sym]`; to join two strings together use `StringJoin[str1,str2]`; to make a symbol out of the joined string use `ToExpression[str]`. Something like `ToExpression[StringJoin[ToString[u],ToString[a]]]` should create the symbol you want. Now you are left with a pattern matching problem. How much should this task be automated?

Comment: `StringInsert[#, "u", 1] & /@ ToString /@ {a, b, c, d}` produces `{"ua", "ub", "uc", "ud"}`.

Comment: Shouldn't `U[a*b, {a, b}]` be `Sqrt[b^2*ua + a^2*ub]` -- i.e., `a` and `b` reversed because `D[a*b, a] = b`?

Comment: Ah, of course you're right. Fixed that

Comment: Why so you write `U[term_Expression, varlist_Expression]`? That argument pattern won't accept any normal arguments -- in particular it won't accept `U[a*b, {a, b}]`.

Comment: You should take a look at Oleksandr's excellent [CovariancePropagation` package](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16803/862)

Answer (score 2):

Another option. Use `ToExpression` to make it a symbol from `String`

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d, u]
lst = {a, b, c, d};
r = Cases[lst, x_ :> ToExpression[ "u" <> ToString[x]]]

FullForm[r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

I might do it this way and make the mark of uncertainty a special head `u`, so that `u[a]` represents the uncertainty of `a`, and so forth.

```
ClearAll[U, u];
SetAttributes[u, HoldAll];
SetAttributes[U, HoldRest];
U[term_, varlist_] := Block[varlist,
  Sqrt[#.#] &[D[term, {varlist}] (u /@ varlist)]
  ]
```

The symbol `u` can be substituted with a function or even defined to give the variable `ua`, `ub` etc.:

```
ClearAll[U, u];
SetAttributes[u, HoldAll];
SetAttributes[U, HoldAll];
u[var_] := Symbol["u" <> SymbolName[Unevaluated[var]]];
U[term_, varlist_] := Block[varlist,
  Sqrt[#.#] &[D[term, {varlist}] (u /@ varlist)]
  ]
```