# Error propagation code

Tags: programming, probability-or-statistics, error-propagation

I have a code for error propagation :-

```
err[F_, w__] := {F[Map[First, List[w]] /. List -> Sequence], 
      Block[{parms = Table[Unique[], {x, 1, Length[List[w]]}], 
            values = Table[List[w][[i, 1]], {i, 1, Length[List[w]]}], 
            errors = Table[List[w][[i, 2]], {i, 1, Length[List[w]]}]}, 
 Sqrt[Total[
 Table[(D[F[parms /. List -> Sequence], parms[[i]]] errors[[i]])^2, 
      {i, 1, Length[values]}] /. 
                      Table[parms[[i]] -> values[[i]], {i, 1, Length[values]}]]]]}
```

I am not able to propagate error in a complex function with this code.For example in case of real function which is defined as :-

```
f[a_, b_] := a + b;
err[f, {2, 0.1}, {3, 0.2}]
```

The output for this function is :- {5, 0.223607}. But in case of complex function say :-

```
f[a_, b_] := Abs[a + I b];
err[f, {2, 0.1}, {3, 0.2}]
```

The output is

```
`{Sqrt[13], Sqrt[(-0.03 + 0. I) Derivative[1][Abs][2 + 3 I]^2]}`
```

In output both values should be a numerical number. How can I modify my code that it will give me a numerical number in output. Thanks.

Please help me .

Comment: Please provide a few sample arguments for `err`, both real and complex.

Comment: You may be interested in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16793/create-an-adaptive-amount-of-local-variables-for-error-propagation/16803#16803): with `expr = ComplexExpand[Abs[a + I b]]`, `PropagateCovariance[expr, {a, b}] // Simplify` is `(2 a b cov[a, b] + a^2 var[a] + b^2 var[b])/(a^2 + b^2)`. This is the (first-order approximation of the) variance in `f` as a function of the variances in `a` and `b`.

Comment: You could approximate the derivatives with finite differences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The troublesome part here is `Abs` is not symbolically differentiable:

```
D[Abs[c], c]
% /. c -> 1
```

> ```
> Abs'[c]
> Abs'[1] (* doesn't make sense *)
> ```

To circumvent this, one way is to use `ND` instead of `D`:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
ND[Abs[a + b I], a, 1] /. b -> 1
```

> ```
> 0.707107
> ```

Another way is to use `ComplexExpand` before differentiation:

```
D[Abs[a + b I] // ComplexExpand, a];
% /. {a -> 1, b -> 1.}
```

> ```
> 0.707107
> ```

Corresponding fixed code:

```
err1[F_, w__] := {F[First /@ {w} /. List -> Sequence], 
     Block[{parms = Table[Unique[], {x, 1, Length[{w}]}], 
    values = Table[{w}[[i, 1]], {i, 1, Length[{w}]}], 
         errors = Table[{w}[[i, 2]], {i, 1, Length[{w}]}]}, 
       Sqrt[
    Total[Table[(D[ComplexExpand[F[parms /. List -> Sequence]], parms[[i]]]*
          errors[[i]])^2, 
               {i, 1, Length[values]}] /. 
      Table[parms[[i]] -> values[[i]], {i, 1, Length[values]}]]]]}

err2[F_, w__] := {F[First /@ {w} /. List -> Sequence], 
     Block[{parms = Table[Unique[], {x, 1, Length[{w}]}], 
    values = Table[{w}[[i, 1]], {i, 1, Length[{w}]}], 
         errors = Table[{w}[[i, 2]], {i, 1, Length[{w}]}]}, 
       Sqrt[
    Total[Table[(ND[F[parms /. List -> Sequence], parms[[i]], values[[i]]]*
          errors[[i]])^2, 
               {i, 1, Length[values]}] /. 
      Table[parms[[i]] -> values[[i]], {i, 1, Length[values]}]]]]}
```

And my attempt to make them conciser:

```
err1c[F_, w__] := 
 Block[{var = 
    Table[Unique[], {Length@{w}}]}, {F @@ #, (#2^2).MapThread[
          ND[F @@ var, #, #2] &, {var, #}]^2 /. Thread[var -> #] // 
      Sqrt} & @@ ({w}\[Transpose])]

err2c[F_, w__] := 
 Block[{var = 
    Table[Unique[], {Length@{w}}]}, {F @@ #, (#2^2).(D[
           F @@ var // ComplexExpand, {var}] /. Thread[var -> #])^2 // 
      Sqrt} & @@ ({w}\[Transpose])]
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Mathematica 12, there are some [experimental functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NumbersWithUncertainty.html) for uncertainty propagation. In particular, see [AroundReplace](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AroundReplace.html)

Using ComplexExpand[] (as suggested by @xzczd),

```
AroundReplace[Abs[x + I y] // ComplexExpand, {x -> Around[2, 0.1], y -> Around[3, 0.2]}]
```

> ```
> Around[3.605551275463989, 0.17541160386140586`]
> ```
>
> [image]