# Error propagation with complex number

Tags: error-propagation

I have an expression of a physical observable in which some input parameters are taken. The corresponding errors of these input parameters are given. To get the error of this observable what code I will use?

Answer (score -2):

Use [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16793/create-an-adaptive-amount-of-local-variables-for-error-propagation) code, for example. Also, check the new Around[] function in Mathematica 12.