# Namespaces in Mathematica

Tags: packages, scoping

In many programming languages one can define a namespace

```
with namespace abc
```

How can the similar be done in *Mathematica*? The `Module` and `Block` commands, can somewhat mimick this, but it is only in the command, it doesn't act as a definition.

How can this be done in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Have a look at `Context`.

Comment: Ah, so with context I can do a`mass=2, b`mass=3. Is there any way to define a block, where everything inside inherits that context?

Comment: @Oskar It sounds like you want to create packages.  Please see: [(29324)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29324/121).  Be aware that you cannot use `Begin` and `End` in a `Module` without great care; see: [(8295)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8295/121)

Comment: Here are two links to documentation pages relevant to your question. [Namespace Management](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/NamespaceManagement.html) and [Package Development](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/PackageDevelopment.html).

Comment: Perhaps this will help clarify things for you. In _Mathematica_, namespaces are the called contexts and packages provide the means for defining persistent namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

In Mathematica, `$ContextPath` contains a list of the contexts where the definition of a symbol is sought (when that symbol has no namespace qualifications). You can use

```
$ContextPath = Prepend[$ContextPath, "abc`"]
```

to achieve what you asked.