# How to unprotect a variable in a package

Tags: packages, version-10, built-in-symbols

In *Mathematica* 9, I had the function(s). I apologize for the weak formatting.

```
RemoveBackground[data_,n_,rng_?NumericQ]:=RemoveBackground[data,n,{{-∞,-rng},{rng,∞}}];

RemoveBackground[data_,n_:2,regions_:{{-∞,∞}}]:= (

RemoveBackground[] = Function[{x}, Evaluate[
    Fit[
        (* select points only in specified regions *)
        Select[
            Flatten[data,Depth[data]-3],
            Function[{pt},Or@@(#[[1]]<=pt[[1]]<=#[[2]]&/@regions)]
        ][[;;,;;2]],
        (* build list of polynomial terms *)
        x^#&/@Range[0,n],
        x
    ]
]];

Map[ReplacePart[#,2->#[[2]]-RemoveBackground[][#[[1]]]]&, data, {-2}] );
```

Now in *Mathematica* 10.0, `RemoveBackground` is a protected function. I know that you can unprotect variables. This worked perfectly fine when I had to do it `Devices`, which they also protected in *Mathematica* 10.0. For some reason since one of the calls to `RemoveBackground` has four arguments it goes red inside the package and continues to give the message

> SetDelayed::write: Tag RemoveBackground in RemoveBackground[data_, n_:2, regions_:{{-inf,inf}}] is protected.

It doesn't seem to to matter where I put `Unprotect[RemoveBackground]`; I keep getting this error. Any ideas as to why?

I have also tried various combinations of `Unprotect` then `Clear` as well.

Comment: `RemoveBackground` is a new system function. You'll need to change the name of yours. See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RemoveBackground.html

Comment: I am aware of this. However this function has been a staple for almost 4 years used throughout various notebooks and packages. It would be much better if there was just a way to remove the definition. For example Sqrt[] is protected but it is extremely easy to change the [definition](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unprotect.html).

Comment: This perfectly illustrates the rule that the user-defined symbols should always start from a lower-case letter.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I don't think it does... all that OP needs to learn is some context management, which is not hard. I don't think that everyone needs to strictly adhere to this maxim for their packages.

Comment: @Nick As others have mentioned, there is a collision with a built-in function. I would not recommend clearing the definitions of the ``System` `` symbol to make way for yours, because you never know what depends internally on what (and it is a bad practice, period.) and you could be doing more damage than you think. Rather, you might want to look at using the full contexts, such as ``MyPackage`MySymbol`` and ``System`MySymbol``. This way, you get to use both functions. You can also change the order in which the contexts appear in `$ContextPath` to determine which definition is used first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not try to redefine a `` System` `` symbol.  It is almost guaranteed to cause trouble sooner or later.  Instead, here's how to deal with name collisions:

**If your function is not part of a package,** then make sure that you never used symbol names that start with a capital letter.  This way you can avoid name collisions.  The same applies to any non-public symbols used in packages.

**If your function is part of a package:**  Let's look at a standard package structure first.  Your package should look like this:

```
BeginPackage["My`"]

RemoveBackground

Begin["`Private`"]

RemoveBackground[___] := "Package symbols"

End[]
EndPackage[]
```

The definition `RemoveBackground[...] := ...` will fail in Mathematica 10, as `RemoveBackground` is a builtin now.  What you need to do at this point is simply specify the full name, including the context, at the point where the symbol name is exported.  This requires a single simple change. The package should look like this now:

```
BeginPackage["My`"]

My`RemoveBackground    (* <-- single change required *)

Begin["`Private`"]

RemoveBackground[___] := "Package symbols"

End[]
EndPackage[]
```

When you load the package, you will get a warning

> RemoveBackground::shdw: Symbol RemoveBackground appears in multiple
>   contexts {My`,System`}; definitions in context My` may shadow or be
>   shadowed by other definitions. >>

but don't worry about it, it's just a warning.  Notice the `$ContextPath` after loading this package:

```
$ContextPath
(* {"My`", "TemplatingLoader`", "PacletManager`", "System`", "Global`"} *)
```

Your package's context appears *before* `` System` `` in the context path.  This means that whenever you type `RemoveBackground`, it will automatically refer to `` My`RemoveBackground `` and not to `` System`RemoveBackground ``.  You do not need to and *should not* try to modify `` System`RemoveBackground ``.  Just create  `` My`RemoveBackground ``, as I described above, and you'll be able to refer to it as `RemoveBackground`, without explicitly needing to mention the context name:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**In summary, the proper way to proceed: Do not modify the builtin `RemoveBackground`.  Instead create an identically named symbol in a different context and let it shadow `` System`RemoveBackground ``.**

Ideally, eventually you'll be able to rename your own function and all code that is using it.  If that's not possible, (or as a temporary measure) use the solution from above.  If you are the only user of your package, then I suggest you do rename your function eventually.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I usually just use the unprotect but this is much cleaner. The code we use was written a while back and it seems like every Mathematica update they add a function or two that overlaps our namespace. I've suggested an overhaul but we tend to use old notebooks quite a bit, and going through and changing it every time is tedious. Plus some of the older members tend to get up in arms over any changes.

Comment: @Nick Even some of the packages that come with Mathematica have conflicts with new builtins and this is how they deal with the conflicts.  Just one thing to keep in mind: make sure any *private* package symbols, i.e. everything that's not explicitly exported inbetween `BeginPackage` and `Begin`, does not start with a capital letter.  If private symbols conflict, it will be harder to fix them.  If public symbols conflict, it's a single change that's needed for each conflict.

Comment: Although if something like that occurs in the private part of the package a simple name change should be possible right? Since that's just the guts and a name change wouldn't change what the package does?

Comment: @Nick Sure.  But why not avoid it in the first place?  Do you have unit tests for the package?  If not, you might not even notice that something broke until someone tries to use an affected function (if you're unlucky, otherwise it'll complain on package load).  `Combinatorica` uses *some* capitalized *private* names, and they have to keep patching it with each release now ...

Comment: We have unit tests for a majority of the packages. Some of them are highly experimental (ie the whole point is we don't know quite what we expect) and I can see the merit in avoiding capital letters in that case.

Comment: @Nick Out of curiosity, are any of these packages public?  If yes, which package is it?  Sounds like a big project.

Comment: Not as of now. It's not huge, about 30 packages and various help notebooks. We do a lot of finite element modeling of semiconductor systems. Some plotting and magnitude finding packages. It has effectively no documentation inside of the code.

Comment: @Nick and Szabolcs: perhaps I am just being a "sore loser" but isn't this answer pretty much a duplicate of the second section of my earlier answer?  The only meaningful difference that I can see is the inclusion of ``Begin["`Private`"]`` which is not strictly required for the illustration at hand (but of course is part of the [standard package pattern](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29324/121)).  May I know why you felt this answer was necessary, and Nick, why it is superior to my own?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No, I don't think there's a difference (other than my confusion on the first part of your answer) but I feel for the sake of the community that one of the answers be accepted. I am awfully new here so if there is a way to have both or neither but have the question be considered 'answered' let me know. I don't mean to play favorites (if that's even possible with complete strangers).

Comment: @Nick It is better to Accept one answer than it is to Accept none, assuming the answer is of course satisfactory.  You cannot Accept two answers.  Which answer you Accept is entirely your prerogative.  I (and I believe as a community, we) are biased toward older answers, all else being equal, so when I see an Accept for a newer answer over and older one with a similar method I assume that the newer one was deemed superior.  If you feel that Szabolcs more clearly articulated the preferred solution the Accept is appropriate.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I will admit that I did not read through your answer in full before posting mine.  I saw the question last night, with one downvote, and I thought that's not fair, this point should be explained clearly.  But I didn't have time to write it up until the morning.  In the morning I went on to write the answer after just briefly checking that your answer is not the same.  I should have checked more carefully.  Now I read your answer in more detail, and I think that it does not make it clear enough that the package context needs to be added only at a single point, ...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ... preferably at the point where the symbol is "exported", i.e. between `BeginPackage` and ``Begin["`Private`"]``.  It is not necessary to refer to the symbol with the fully qualified name throughout the package, just the very first time the symbol is mentioned.  Updating the package takes only a single change.  I also felt that it should be made clear that this is the standard way to handle name conflicts, it fits in very well with the usual package structure, and overwriting built-ins is a bad idea.

Comment: I acknowledge that I did not explicitly state the first point but I hoped that the fact that I did explicitly state that the new context (``foo` ``) would be prioritized over ``System` `` and the immediate example I gave of its "bare" use would make that apparent.  As for the latter I am not sure how I could have been more clear without being needlessly emphatic.  (continued)

Comment: I wrote: "The preferred course of action is to use only Symbols starting with lower-case letters or call your function with an explicit context" which I hoped would indicate that one or the other of these is the standard/preferred/common action, and: "Rather than trampling on a System` function which may or may not be used internally you can define your new function in a user context, then prioritize your context over System" which I thought fairly clearly implied ("trampling") that overwriting a System function was a bad idea.  I ask seriously: how do you think I should have written it?

Comment: Anyway, a +1 for your answer for finding the phrasing that the OP preferred. :-)

Answer (score 10):

### Caveat

This is the known risk with any user definition upon a Symbol starting with a capital letter that is not explicitly called from a user context.  It is not adequate to believe that you will not need any new functionality that is added as the new function may itself be required by other functions which you do need, including existing ones if they are rewritten using the new abstraction.

The preferred course of action is to use only Symbols starting with lower-case letters or call your function with an explicit context, e.g. `` Nick`RemoveBackground ``.  By convention the first method should never conflict with built-in functions, and so long as Wolfram Research doesn't release a standard package named Nick you should be OK with the second.

Since "this function has been a staple for almost 4 years used throughout various notebooks and packages" you require a work-around.

## Overwrite the System function

Since the `` System` `` function is not `Locked` we can at least attempt to enact a direct substitution.  The first reason you had trouble is that the native function definition is not fully loaded initially.  I ran into this surprise myself a few years ago:

- [Why do I have to evaluate this twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5649379)

The second reason is that you did not clear the existing definition before proceeding.

Incorporating a fix for each issue your redefinition works:

```
Quiet @ Quiet @ RemoveBackground[1] (* preload *);

Unprotect[RemoveBackground];

ClearAll[RemoveBackground] (* remove old definitions *);           

RemoveBackground[data_, n_, rng_?NumericQ] := . . .
```

## Define your function in a user context

Rather than trampling on a `` System` `` function which may or may not be used internally you can define your new function in a user context, then prioritize your context over `` System` ``.  This results in [shadowing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8297/121) and red warning syntax, but it also lets your function work as desired without actually overwriting the built-in or having to rename every appearance of your function.  Rather than using your full definition I shall show how this works with a very simple example.  Imagine that I want `Plus` to concatenate strings rather than add numbers:

```
BeginPackage["foo`"];

foo`Plus[s__] := StringJoin[s]

EndPackage[];
```

> Plus::shdw: Symbol Plus appears in multiple contexts {`` foo` ``,`` System` ``}; definitions in context `` foo` `` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions. >>

The new context `` foo` `` is prefixed to [`$ContextPath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$ContextPath.html) which means that its definitions are prioritized.  Now a use of `Plus` is highlighted in red (by default) to indicate shadowing, and my definition is used:

[image]

Crucially however `` System`Plus `` remains unharmed:

```
System`Plus[1, 2, 3]
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

It is also used if the short form of `Plus` is used as this is interpreted as `` System`Plus `` directly:

```
1 + 2 + 3
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

Comment: Okay I agree with your second method, that works fine (other then having to live with constant red text). Your first method however seems to not quite work for a strange reason. If I run the code with the Quiet @ Quiet ... RemoveBackground doesn't work properly. It seems to be in that first line I have above. 
`RemoveBackground[data_,n_,rng_?NumericQ]:=RemoveBackground[data,n,{{-\[Infinity‌​],-rng},{rng,\[Infinity]}}];`
Everything after the second n, to the colon is red and I get the Set::write error. I would like to believe it is because the system RemoveBackground can only take two arguments

Comment: @Nick I am having trouble replicating the problem you describe.  Do you have time to join me in [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/wolfram-mathematica)?

Comment: Indeed, I will be around for the next hour or so.

Comment: Okay if I pull out the code above and put it into its own package this works fine (I still get a Set::write error but the code executes). I'm not going to go through and figure out what the difference is between the full package and the snippet I pulled out.