# Isolating characters in a string

Tags: string-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation, parsing

I'm struggling to find the right function in mathematica to isolate specific characters in a string. I have got a formula as string (I imported it from an excelfile) like this:

**y = 0.97*x1 + 0.521*x2 - 30.21 - 0.07431*x3 - 0.126*x4 - 0.1939*x5 - 0.361*x6**

Now I want to isolate the coefficients, e.g. 0.97,0.521 from the x's and maybe store it seperately, so that I know which coefficients were for which x. I thought this would be easily done and I browsed through the help of mathematica, but I couln't find any example which helps me so far. Maybe some of you can help me out which functions is best for this task?

Comment: `CoefficientRules[#, Variables@#] &@ToExpression[str]`

Comment: `Coefficient[#, Variables@#] &@ToExpression[str]` ... etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the internal expression parser:

```
string = "y = 0.97*x1 + 0.521*x2 - 30.21 - 0.07431*x3 - 0.126*x4 - 0.1939*x5 - 0.361*x6";

Cases[
  ToHeldExpression[string],
  s_Symbol * Except[_Symbol, n_?NumericQ] :> {HoldForm[s], n},
  {-2}
]
```

> ```
> {{x1,0.97}, {x2,0.521}, {x3,-0.07431}, {x4,-0.126}, {x5,-0.1939}, {x6,-0.361}}
> ```

- Note use of [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldForm.html) to keep Symbols unevaluated in case they have values assigned.
- In this simple case the rule `s_Symbol * n_ :> {HoldForm[s], n}` could be used but I believe the code above is more robust.
- `ToHeldExpression` is a deprecated function but still entirely usable, and more concise than `ToExpression[string, InputForm, Hold]`.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is just for exercise purposes, I would use `Coefficient` way.

```
string = "y = 0.97*x1 + 0.521*x2 - 30.21 - 0.07431*x3 - 0.126*x4 - 0.1939*x5 - 0.361*x6";

StringCases[
  StringReplace[string, "- " -> "-"],
  c : NumberString ~~ _ ~~ x : ("x" ~~ DigitCharacter) :> {c, x}]
```

> ```
> {{"0.97", "x1"}, {"0.521", "x2"}, {"-0.07431", "x3"}, {"-0.126", "x4"},
>  {"-0.1939", "x5"}, {"-0.361", "x6"}}
> ```

When there are cases like "+ x2" we need one more replacement:

```
string = "y = 0.97*x1 + x2 - 30.21 - x3 - 0.126*x4 - 0.1939*x5 - 0.361*x6";

StringCases[
 Fold[StringReplace, string, {s : ("+ " | "- ") ~~ "x" :> s <> "1.*x", "- " -> "-"}]
 ,
 c : NumberString ~~ _ ~~ x : ("x" ~~ DigitCharacter) :> {c, x}]
```

> ```
> {{"0.97", "x1"}, {"1.", "x2"}, {"-1.", "x3"}, {"-0.126", "x4"}, 
>  {"-0.1939", "x5"}, {"-0.361", "x6"}}
> ```

Comment: I assumed that the x's were arbitrary symbols, but of that is not the case this is quite good.  However you lost the signs of the coefficients which may not be acceptable; perhaps you could add an alternative that retains them?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ok, done. Yes it is not general solution. Also free coefficient is skipped, I don't know if it is acceptable.

Comment: I skipped free coefficients as well because it seemed to me that the OP wanted to pair values. +1 with the correction.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ha, you were not careful enough, it skipped "+ x2" cases too!

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways it might be done. This is one example. Here is something like your string:

```
str = "y=0.97*x1+0.52*x2-30.21-0.07*x3";
```

I do not take the full version, since you did not give it in M form, which normally you should have done. Now, let us make a list out of it:

```
 list = List @@ ToExpression[str]
(* {-30.21, 0.97 x1, 0.52 x2, -0.07 x3}   *)
```

This list is transformed into required one as follows:

```
 list /. a_ /; Characters[ToString@a][[1]] == "x" -> 1

(*   {-30.21, 0.97, 0.52, -0.07}  *)
```

Here is another simple solution based on the assumption that you have always the numeration of x-s monotonously increasing,i.e. the list of three elements will be  x1, x2 x3 and not x1, x28, x5. In this case one can do as follows:

```
   rule = Table[
  ToExpression[ToString[x] <> ToString[i]] -> 1, {i, 1, 
   Length[list] - 1}]

(*  {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 1, x3 -> 1}   *)
```

and then using the list from the previous solution:

```
    list /. rule

(*   {-30.21, 0.97, 0.52, -0.07}  *)
```

That' it. Have fun.

Comment: The problems with this kind of approach are that 1) `y` gets evaluated, which is an undesirable side effect and also, 2) if the `xn` already have assigned values in the .nb it fails. That's why I posted my "solutions" as comments in the question

Comment: @belisarius You need no excuses to post a different solution: the more solutions - the better. I love to learn from others to see possibilities I failed to see myself.

Comment: Identifying problems is quite different from having solutions :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I can work with that. It helps me a lot to see different approaches to a problem btw :)

Answer (score 2):

Using [jVincent's `ContextScope[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10397/193)

```
m`str1 = "y = 0.97*x1 + 0.521*x2 - 30.21 - 0.07431*x3 - 0.126*x4 - 0.1939*x5 - 0.361*x6";
ContextScope["m`", {SymbolName /@ Variables@#, 
                    Coefficient[#, Variables@#]} &@ToExpression[str1] // Transpose]
(*
{{"x1", 0.97`}, {"x2", 0.521`}, {"x3", -0.07431`}, 
 {"x4", -0.126`}, {"x5", -0.1939`}, {"x6", -0.361`}}
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm still new to `String` `Patterns` here is another entry using `StringCases`.

```
string = "y = 0.97*x1 + 0.521*x2 - 30.21 - 0.07431*x3 - 0.126*x4 - 0.1939*x5 - 0.361*x6";

StringCases[string, s : ({" ", " + ", " - "} ~~ NumberString) ~~ "*" ~~ 
   x : ("x" ~~ DigitCharacter ..) :> {x, ToExpression@s}]
```

Gives:

> ```
> {{"x1", 0.97}, {"x2", 0.521}, {"x3", -0.07431}, {"x4", -0.126}, {"x5", -0.1939}, {"x6",-0.361}}
> ```

Note the use of `DigitCharacter ..` for situations with variables like `x10, x11` etc.

Kuba pointed out that cases like `"y = x2"` cannot be handled by the above method, so we do some `StringReplace`ment before proceeding:

```
string2 = "y = 0.97*x1 + x2 - 30.21 - x3 - 0.126*x4 - 0.1939*x5 - 0.361*x6";
```

Now

```
rp = StringReplace[string2, " " ~~ x : ("x" ~~ DigitCharacter ..) :> " 1" ~~ "*" ~~ x]
```

Then as before:

```
StringCases[rp, s : ({" ", " + ", " - "} ~~ NumberString) ~~ "*" ~~ 
                x : ("x" ~~ DigitCharacter ..) :> {x, ToExpression@s}]
```

> ```
> {{"x1", 0.97}, {"x2", 1}, {"x3", -1}, {"x4", -0.126}, {"x5", -0.1939}, {"x6", -0.361}}
> ```

Comment: You missed what I've missed: `"y = x2"`

Comment: @Kuba, Ah, thanks!

Comment: @Kube see my edit please.

Comment: it seems ok now :) also more tidy than mine +1

Comment: @Kuba, thanks for looking through it :)