# Does every function know about other function?

Tags: symbolic

The Mathematica function `Area` knows about `Sphere`. For example the following output.

```
Area[Sphere[]]
```

> 4 Pi

Does this mean each function knows about the other? Is there a way to find out which functions knows about which? For example is there a way to find out what all other functions `Area` is aware of?

Comment: if you look at help for `Area` it says it gives area for 2D `region`. And under scope, you will see list of regions it knows about. Basically any `ref/Region` it should give its area.

Answer (score 0):

Those functions are in the System` path, which is automatically loaded.

See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$ContextPath.html

and `` ?System`* `` to see the included functions.

There is a post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10397/363) where jVincent excludes the System context for testing.

Comment: I am not looking for where Mathematica loads the function's from. I am looking for information on how one function knows about the other. Is there a way to find what all the other inputs the **Area** function would support