# Functions that creates symbol in a specific context

Tags: contexts, core-language

I'm trying to make a function `f` that takes a symbol, a value, and a context, and creates the symbol in the requested context and assigns it the passed value. The obvious doesn't work. I.e.:

```
Attributes[f]={HoldAllComplete};
f[symbol_,value_,context_]:=(Begin[context];Set[symbol,value];End[])
```

Creates the symbol in the current context, as opposed to the one that is passed as an argument. This seems to happen because the FrontEnd, as soon as it sees `f` getting evaluated, creates the symbol in the current context despite `HoldAllComplete`. I tried adding `Remove[symbol]` to the function but that doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: I should clarify that I really need to pass the symbol, not the symbol's name. I realize it can be done when passing the symbol's name, but I can't use that approach because it would break a lot of existing code. I realize that I can overload the function and have a legacy version that takes the symbol and does not allow contexts, and one that takes in strings and does allow for contexts, but ideally I would like to avoid such a hack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that if you pass a symbol, it will be created already during the parsing stage, when you pass it, in the current context. Therefore I suggest to pass its string name instead. This function will do the job:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[symbolName_String, value_, context_] :=
  Block[{$ContextPath},
    BeginPackage[context];
    ToExpression[
       symbolName, 
       StandardForm, 
       Function[name, Set[name, value], HoldAll]
    ];
    EndPackage[]
  ]
```

for example

```
f["a", 10, "Test`"]
Test`a

(* 10 *)
```

If you still want to pass a symbol, you can use this:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[symbol_, value_, context_] :=
  With[{set = MakeBoxes[symbol = value]},
    Block[{$ContextPath},
      BeginPackage[context];
      ReleaseHold[MakeExpression@set];
      EndPackage[]]];
```

which is a version of the code I used [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/595/is-it-possible-to-use-begin-and-end-inside-a-manipulate/598#598). But be aware that you will also create the symbol `symbol` in the current working context, so you may additionally use `Remove` to remove it.

So, for example:

```
f[a, 20, "Test`"]
Test`a

(* 20 *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this won't work for my needs. See the comment that I added to the question.

Comment: @OleksandrR. The symbol with the same name may exist in some other context currently on the `$ContextPath`, in which case that one will be used and assigned a value - which is obviously not what one would like here. The use of `BeginPackage` and `EndPackage` effectively allows to reset the `$ContextPath` to just ``{"MyContext`","System`"}``, which solves this problem.

Comment: @MohammedAlQuraishi I added a symbol-based version, see my edit.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Great, thank you!

Comment: I just spent a while recreating and debugging code equivalent to your second method.  I really should read your answers better before starting on my own.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I will use your usual reply: "great minds think alike" :)

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is what you want:

```
f[symname_String, value_, context_] := 
 (Begin[context];
  With[{s = Symbol[symname]}, Set[s, value]]; End[])
```

Then use it like this:

```
 f["myvar", 4, "MyContext`"]
```

Verify:

```
? MyContext`myvar
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Really? Maybe if you do a ClearAll[f], or restart a new, fresh Mathematica session? or give the function another name? I am guessing your old definition for f is in conflict with the one I propose. Notice the idea is the same as the one by Leonid, give the name as a string "myvar" instead of myvar

Comment: It does work for me. But, invoking `f` twice for the same symbol will produce an error. You need to take Leonid's approach of using `ToExpression` rather than `Symbol` if you want to avoid that.

Comment: @QuantumMathematica Yes indeed, on a fresh kernel it does work.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this meets your specification:

```
Attributes[f] = {HoldAllComplete};

f[symbol_, value_, context_] :=
 ToHeldExpression[context <> SymbolName@Unevaluated@symbol] /. _[x_] :> (x = value)
```