# `Slot` (#) interfering with evaluation

Tags: list-manipulation, scoping, pure-function

In the following I am using one function `makeFunc` to assemble two functions `a[t]` and `b[t]` to pass to use in the formation of a `Table`.  `makeFunc` appears to be doing its job appropriately because the error messages and `Trace` show that it has assembled `a[t]` and that the `Table` construct has evaluated the `t` portion of the function. However, `a[t]` is not evaluating itself and so the `Table` appears as `a[0]`, `a[30]`, etc.

```
tempMakeTableAn[{analEqs_, concs_, initConcs_, rateConstants_, 
    timeDom_, timeInc_}] :=
  Module[{a, b},
   a[t_] := 
    aZero Exp[-k1 t] /. Evaluate[Join[initConcs, rateConstants]];
   b[t_] := 
    bZero + 1 - aZero a[t] /. Evaluate[Join[initConcs, rateConstants]];

   makeFunc[conc_, time_] := Evaluate[conc[time]];

   Column[{Table[{a[t], b[t]}, {t, 0, 300, 30}],
     Table[makeFunc[#, timeDom[[1]]] & /@ concs, {t, 0, 300, 30}]}]    
];

tempMakeTableAn[{{Hold[a[t_] := aZero Exp[-k1 t], 
    b[t_] := bZero + 1 - aZero a[t]]}, {a, b}, {aZero -> 1, 
   bZero -> 0}, {k1 -> .01}, {t, 0, 300}, {30}}]
```

> {
>   {{{1, 0}, {0.740818, 0.259182}, {0.548812, 0.451188}, {0.40657, 
>      0.59343}, {0.301194, 0.698806}, {0.22313, 0.77687}, {0.165299, 
>      0.834701}, {0.122456, 0.877544}, {0.090718, 0.909282}, {0.0672055,
>       0.932794}, {0.0497871, 0.950213}}},
>
> {{{a[0], b[0]}, {a[30], b[30]}, {a[60], b[60]}, {a[90], 
>      b[90]}, {a[120], b[120]}, {a[150], b[150]}, {a[180], 
>      b[180]}, {a[210], b[210]}, {a[240], b[240]}, {a[270], 
>      b[270]}, {a[300], b[300]}}}
>   }

This appears to have something to do with the way that I am utilizing the `Slot` (#) as you can see that when I entered in `a[t]` and `b[t]` directly, the `Table` works.

I *think* that this may have to do with scoping of the variables, because if I remove `a` and `b` as declared variables in the `Module`, everything works as expected.  I.e. `a` and `b` get defined globally and the expected `Table` appears.

I have also tried some judiciously placed `Evaluate` statements to see if that is what was needed, but that didn't make any changes.

I have found a couple of questions that I thought might be applicable ([Using pure functions in Table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7756/using-pure-functions-in-table),[Evaluate[] seems to not work inside Button[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523836/evaluate-seems-to-not-work-inside-button/)), but since the construct works when the variables are declared globally, I don't understand why it doesn't work when they are declared within the module.

Any help would be appreciated. [If somebody can come up with a better Title, have at it.  This was the best that I could figure out].

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html) work exactly as it should, because it is designed to implement *lexical scoping*. Take it away, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_scope#Lexical_scoping_vs._dynamic_scoping):

> In *lexical scoping* (or *lexical scope*; also called *static scoping* or *static scope*), if a variable name's scope is a certain function, then its scope is the program text of the function definition: within that text, the variable name exists, and is bound to the variable's value, but outside that text, the variable name does not exist.

Thus, when you declare these symbols `a` and `b` at the top of your `Module`, Mathematica will create two new symbols (using [`Unique`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unique.html)) and replace all occurrences of `a` and `b` within the `Module`'s body with those new symbols. Look what happens when we have a `Module` that just returns the new symbols:

```
Module[{a, b}, {a, b}]
```

> ```
> {a$1138, b$1138}
> ```

That's an example; the digits that come after the `$` are appended by Mathematica to make the symbols unique. The same thing is happening in your first `tempMakeTableAn` function definition, so the `a`s and `b`s appearing within the `Module` have nothing to do with the `a`s and `b`s that are being defined/assigned in the second definition.

Comment: So that helps me understand what is going wrong, but is there a way I can force the second definition to not be a redefinition but use the `Module`'s definition?

Comment: @rasher Rasher's comments to his answer above provided the fix that I needed. Thanks for your answer, it helped me understand the situation.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* this does what you're trying to accomplish. Note, you're not using "pure functions" anywhere in your code, I just jiggered it to get what I think you're after, there are almost certainly cleaner ways to do what I think you're trying to do (like actually using pure functions, etc.)

```
tempMakeTableAn[{analEqs_, concs_, initConcs_, rateConstants_, 
    timeDom_, timeInc_}] := Module[{a, b},

   (ReleaseHold[analEqs /. Evaluate[Join[initConcs, rateConstants]]]);

   makeFunc[conc_, time_] := Evaluate[conc[time]];

   Table[makeFunc[#, timeDom[[1]]] & /@ concs, {t, 0, 300, 30}]];

tempMakeTableAn[{{Hold[a[t_] := aZero Exp[-k1 t]; 
    b[t_] := bZero + 1 - aZero a[t]]}, {a, b}, {aZero -> 1, 
   bZero -> 0}, {k1 -> .01}, {t, 0, 300}, {30}}]

(*
{{1., 0.}, {0.740818, 0.259182}, {0.548812, 0.451188}, {0.40657, 
  0.59343}, {0.301194, 0.698806}, {0.22313, 0.77687}, {0.165299, 
  0.834701}, {0.122456, 0.877544}, {0.090718, 0.909282}, {0.0672055, 
  0.932794}, {0.0497871, 0.950213}}
*)
```

Comment: I had used almost exactly the same construct. The problem is that the `ReleaseHold` defines `a[t]` and `b[t]` globally, and I want to avoid that (if I can).  A related post to this problem is http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/595/is-it-possible-to-use-begin-and-end-inside-a-manipulate and I tried to utilize that fix here, but did not manage it.  For this reason, I had switched to defining them explicitly at the beginning in the `Module`.  Thanks also for the correction on the use of the term "Pure Function".  How can I better describe the use of the [#]&/. format?

Comment: Actually, if I could make what you answered work (with `a` and `b` being defined within the `Module` and not globally), that would be a much better solution for me.

Comment: @AndyMobley: change `Module` to `Block`, a/b will be local.

Comment: That fixed it. Oh, I need to learn how to use `Block`. I'll start by re(re(re))reading http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs   I actually marked it as my very first favorite when I first joined (not that long ago), but haven't learned the lessons yet. Thanks. Do you want to edit the answer to reflect the `Block` before I accept it?

Comment: AND . . . It appears that I can even define the declared variables in the `Block` on the fly by using the `concs` variable that came with the function. That is **exactly** what I wanted.