# Begin[] again (V12.1)

Tags: contexts

Some questions related to `$Context` and `$ContextPath` have already been asked and answered, but I still cannot fully grasp the concept. Evaluating

`` CompoundExpression[Begin["Ctx1`"], x = 1, End[], {Ctx1`x, x}] ``

in a pristine kernel yields `` {Ctx1`x, 1} ``. However, evaluating each level 1 statement in turn in a pristine kernel results in `{1, x}`. If this behaviour complies with the design, where is it documented?

Comment: It must be due to some quirk of the parsing like in this answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/598/72682 I'm surprised that printing out the contexts gives the correct printouts but still gets it wrong ```CompoundExpression[Print[$Context], Begin["Ctx1`"], Print[$Context], x = 1, End[], Print[$Context], {Ctx1`x, x}]```

Comment: It behaves as expected, see also this answer with doc links: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119187/5478. @flinty Print and Begin are evaluated after the whole compound expression was parsed so there is no way for Begin to affect parsing of `x`.

Comment: @Kuba Many thanks. It really is stated quite clearly in `tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThings#5934` about "Setting Up Wolfram Language Packages". The question is resolved.