# Context Manipulation within Scoping Constructs

Tags: syntax, scoping, contexts

In the following the full context form of `Test` is not required as `` "Aaa`" `` is added to `$ContextPath`

```
Aaa`Test[x_] := x + 1;
context = "Aaa`";
PrependTo[$ContextPath, context];
Context@Test

(* "Aaa`" *)
```

The same however, doesn't seem to apply within scoping constructs.

```
Quit
```

```
Aaa`Test[x_] := x + 1;
With[{context = "Aaa`"},
 PrependTo[$ContextPath, context];
 Context@Test
 ]

(* "Global`" *)
```

Note that `Quit` is needed as the expected behaviour happens if evaluated twice.
I find this surprising as it indicates an a priori parsing of the body within scoping constructs (the same applies if `With` is replaced by `Block` or `Module`) whereas I would have anticipated that this would be changeable along with normal control-flow expectations. Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Related: [Context of localized (dynamic) symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75323/27951), [Local variables in Module leak into Global context](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8295/27951). Although those questions focus on Module, With is also a scoping construct.

Comment: @MarcoB Those links describe a slightly different situation describing conflicting local/global variables. They did however, contain a couple of relevant answers (now linked in the self-answer) that led to correcting clearly a long-held misunderstanding of WL's evaluation sequence. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The scoping construct is only relevant in so far as it groups the code into a singly parsed block. Hence, the same "unexpected" behaviour results from *any* type of grouping

```
(Aaa`Test[x_] := x + 1;
 context = "Aaa`";
 PrependTo[$ContextPath, context];
 Context@Test
 )

(* "Global`" *)
```

Hence, the WL possesses a parsing/evaluation sequence [from input to input (line to line)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7918403) giving a hybrid parsing/run-time evaluation sequence (n.b. loading the first snippet in a .m/.wl file produces identical output). If all needs to be contained in a given scope one workaround as [per this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/598/2249) is to delay the parsing with strings/boxes although probably easier is just to set up desired contexts in a previous input.